# service broker/resource govenor

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, resource-governor

Is  it possible to configure service broker to work with resource governor?  Currently all commands are being sent to the internal group but I want them to go elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately not. [An option to control Service Broker activation procedures by Resource Governor](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/780270/an-option-to-control-service-broker-activation-procedures-by-resource-governor)

Comment: @RemusRusanu turn your comment into an answer and I'll upvote it.